# getting an error while passing this query to get login name from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Help me getting login_name from database stored in table named users m working in ci

And applying this query and its giving a error in it

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT login_name FROM users WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."')"";

$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

echo  $row['login_name'] ;
```

I'm getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in
>   K:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\users\users.php on
>   line 56

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows your error. Your text editor should have too.

Comment: u have one extra " at the end of the query )""

Answer (score 0):

You have your quotes mixed up, try this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT login_name FROM users WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT login_name FROM users WHERE email='" . $_POST['email'] . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace to this.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT login_name FROM users WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue with your quotes.
Try something like this:

> $sql = mysql_query("SELECT login_name FROM users WHERE email='" . $_POST['email'] . "'");

Answer (score 0):

It has extra double quotes at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't directly an answer to your question, I strongly suggest you check out http://bobby-tables.com/php.html. It shows the correct syntax for what you're trying to do, as well as showing how to prevent sql injection, which the code you've shown is vulnerably to.